# Abel's test and Leibnitz's test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence

Hi does anyone know how Abel's test and Leibnitz's test( also called the 'alternating series test' for convergence) are related? Is the alternating series test sometimes called Abel's test? The alternating series test states:

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a non-negative sequence of numbers, which are monotone decreasing to $0$. Then the series $\sum(-1)^{n}a_{n}$ converges, and $$\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}a_{n}\right\vert \leq a_{1}$$

Thanks

Comment: I never remember Abel's test, instead I remember its proof. The idea is that to study the convergence of $\sum x_ny_n$ one uses summation by parts to reduce it to the convergence of $\sum (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)(y_{n+1}-y_n)$ plus the two terms that are missing. Following the same idea one can prove Leibnitz's test. Use the technique with $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n=a_n$.

Comment: Abel's test and the Alternating Series Test (also known as Leibniz's test) are both easy consequences of Dirichlet's test: If $(a_n)$ is a sequence which decreases to 0 and $(b_n)$ is a sequence with bounded partial sums, then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

Comment: They both can be used to prove convergence of an alternating series. Abel's test is more general, and can be used to prove Leibniz's test.